Key isn't auto-incrementing
I have a view model class setup like this:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Proj1.Models
{
    public class Groups
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? GrpName { get; set; }
    }
}

I thought {Key] had a built in autoincrementing function. So I created a database with three tables like this like this:
var dbfile = GenDbName();    // This generates a database file name.
var dbpath = Path.Combine(datLoc, dbfile);     
var Options = new SQLiteConnectionString(dbpath, true);
var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Options);

await conn.CreateTablesAsync<LakSettings, Groups, PassWrds>();

And for the Groups table, I added records like this:
var grp = new Groups()
{
    GrpName = "Computer"
};
await conn.InsertAsync(grp);

grp = new Groups()
{
    GrpName = "Email"
};
await conn.InsertAsync(grp);

grp = new Groups()
{
    GrpName = "Internet"
};

await conn.InsertAsync(grp);

And when I look at the Id column of the Group table, each record has the same value of 0.00.
So what's going wrong?

Pleae show us the CREATE TABLE syntax that was generated by CreateTablesAsync  - you'll need to enable logging.

I did not use a 'CREATE TABLE' command. all I used was a Group class with a '[Key]' attribute before the Id field and I created the tables with the command 'await conn.CreateTablesAsync<LakSettings, Groups, PassWrds>();'  Should I be using a different command and namespace?

I know you didn't directly or personally run CREATE TABLE in whatever DB tooling you're using, but all SQL-based RDBMSs (MySQL, Oracle, Access, Sqlite and more) all use CREATE TABLE - its a real ISO standard after-all. EF will generate  CREATE TABLE statements based on your entity class types and run the generated SQL all within its CreateTablesAsync. Please take a moment to learn how EF works...

Is it SQLite-net library? Add tag!

In the class definition, try this syntax for the primary key:
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }

This should create the column as unique and auto-incrementing.

Yes, that would solve my problem with the auto-incrementing. However, when I tried to update a specific row, using the command 'await conn.UpdateAsync(lst)' where lst is a List that contains the row from the class that has a field set as PrimaryKey

Hi @BobGatto, do you want to insert a row of data? Is there any relationship between these data? Have you tried updating them one by one?
